# Joomla Login - Some Times Redirect Wrong Page.

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I First Assigned Joomla Login Redirect page is My Profile using Login Module.

[image]

It's Working.. But Some times, When user attempt Login It's Redirect to www.example.com/index.php/component/users/?view=login&Itemid=171.

How can Fix this Issue

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the component you are using. Suppose I browse a page where you installed a component like community builder and then I click on login. What it does is it will add a redirect url which will override the login module settings. Also if you are not logging in through the module but through other component then it will not work.